# I cannot scrap the image links with IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The link I try to export images is this

https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_dkr=1&iconV2Request=true&_blrs=recall_filtering&_ssn=autobuffy&store_cat=0&store_name=autobuffy&_oac=1&_sop=10&_ipg=120&rt=nc&_pgn=5

This is the page 5.

The link is in the cell A1. So, The formula I use is

=IMPORTXML(A1,"//img/@src")

This formula works for the pages 1, 2, 3, and 4 but it does not work for the pages after 5.

Why does not this formula work for page 5?

This is the result below I receive.

[image: the result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After OP mentioned that was able to gather data from pages 1 to 4 but not five, I decided to load the fifth page using google app script and check the contents

The result was:

[ebay screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDuGx.png)

where you can see the message "BOT_MAX_PAGE_NUMBER_EXCEEDED:Localized error message is missing."

Actually if you execute this formula instead, you can gather the same message in google sheets.

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@class='s-message__content']")
```

As you can see here:

[google sheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dGlL.png)

So the answer is that ebay is now allowing this kind of scraping techniques beyond page 4.

Comment: It explains a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to import data from a website that heavily relies on javascript to render the contents and that is not allowed in these formulas.

Gooogle Sheets doesn't load scripts for security reasons.

Check out this link for more information: https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/wiki/import-html-xml/#wiki_common_pitfalls

Comment: How come it works for the pages 1 to 4 then?